# Find Laplace Transform of trigonometric function using unit step function and t-shifting. (5.3-40)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, proof-verification, laplace-transform, solution-verification

Please check my work. Did I calculate the following Laplace Transform correctly?

$$f(t)=sin(t)u(t-\frac{\pi}{2})$$

**My solution**:

Use the following corollary from the second shifting theorem (t-shift)...

$$\mathcal{L}\{g(t)u(t-a)\}=e^{-as}\mathcal{L}\{g(t+a)\}$$

where...

$$f(t)=g(t+a)$$

with $g(t)=sin(t)$ and $a=\pi/2$

$$g(t+a)=g(t+\frac{\pi}{2})=sin(t+\frac{\pi}{2})$$

reduce the sine term to a simpler form...

$$sin(t+\frac{\pi}{2})=cos(\frac{\pi}{2})sin(t)+sin(\frac{\pi}{2})cos(t)$$

$$=0\cdot\sin(t)+1\cdot cos(t)=cos(t)$$

hence...

$$\mathcal{L}\{sin(t)u(t-\frac{\pi}{2})\}=e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}s}\mathcal{L}\{cos(t)\}$$

$$F(s)=\frac{e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}s}}{s^2+1}$$

Comment: It should be $F(s)=\frac{s e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}s}}{s^2+1}$ since Laplace transform of $\cos(t)$ is $\frac{s}{s^2+1}$.

Comment: Thank you! You are correct. It was just an oversight. I am just glad my methodology was correct.

Comment: Your approach is correct! You are welcome!